# display multiple forms in one page

Tags: zend-framework2

Just stated zend2 a week ago and new to framework environment.

Using zend2 tutorial, i created different forms, but now what I need is to display three forms in one page.

report/add
company/add
users/add

output three different form using their own view files. But I need three of them one single page.

I tried searching a lot, but no relevant result found. Question maybe repetitive, if so please drop reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be interested in [`\Zend\View\Helper\Partial`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper). This `ViewHelper` allows you to render different view-files in your current one. Let's assume your scenario where you have some sort of dashboard that will render several forms.

**form_one.phtml**

```
$form = $this->form;
//render your Form
```

**form_two.phtml**

```
$form = $this->form;
//render your Form
```

So far so good, nothing extraordinary here. Let's take a quick detour into your `DashboardController` or rather the specific `dashboardAction()`

```
public function dashboardAction()
{
    $formOne = new FormOne();
    $formTwo = new FormTwo();

    return array(
        'form_one' => $formOne,
        'form_two' => $formTwo
    );
}
```

With this setup, the variables `form_one` and `form_two` will be available inside your `dashboard.phtml`

**dashboard.phtml**

```
<h2>FormOne</h2>
<?=$this->partial('form_one.phtml', array('form' => $this->form_one));?>

<h2>FormTwo</h2>
<?=$this->partial('form_two.phtml', array('form' => $this->form_two));?>
```

With this setup you make each Form known to the specific rendering-view-file as `form` or with less magic `$this->form`

Comment: Thanks Sam, it worked. And your tutorials are awesome. They are actually great help for beginners.

Comment: You could use view model nesting too, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342330/zend-framework-2-two-templates-in-one-layout/15361266#15361266) to see how it can be done.